# Open Source Project Analytics Sites?

Tags: open-source, analytics

I have seen at least one site in the past that had analytics on Open Source projects, describing lines of code, hours worked, number of check-ins, all sorts of stuff.

Does anyone know of any of those sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They employ different [metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metrics), an example would be [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/).